# Exit-Reentry for Saudi Arabia

Tags: saudi-arabia

I have got an exit reentry visa for Saudi Arabia. Can anyone let me know which country visit is cheaper near by Saudi Arabia.

Thanks in advance.
Best Regards,
Venkat

Comment: I'm sorry, but I voted to close as primarily opinion-based. What type of budget do you have? Egypt might be a possibility. The gulf states, I think, tend to be expensive.

Comment: @mkennedy regardless of the traveler's budget, options can be ranked in order of cost and the least expensive is the answer to this question.

Comment: @phoog Regardless of that, we are not a travel agency.